# Specific subfolder check

Tags: directory, structure

Could you help me on building a Powershell script to do the following?

In a certain folder structure check if the "Old projects" exists and if it is not empty tell the user of the script how many files and folders are in it.

Example:

```
F:\Project DATA\Customer A\Projects\Old projects
```

The customer name (in this example Customer A) is different all the time, the Projects and "Old projects" folders however are in the same folder everytime. For some customers there is no "Old projects" folder, so the script needs the check if the folder exists first.

Hope you can help me on the right track with this ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A combination of some scripts that I found and have changed but this didn't work out the way it should be...

Comment: Using a fixed path would be a lot easier but in my case the customer folder name is different in every case...

Comment: I'm also running into the problem that Get-ChildItem is limited to 260 characters while the structure that I use has more...